# pushPayload can not update property of model which is set previously

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

As the following, user has serviceinfo, which is of userService type:

```
User = DS.Model.extend({
    serviceinfo: belongsTo('userService', {async: true})
});

UserService = DS.Model.extend({
   online: attr('number', {defaultValue: 0})
});
```

When the app start, online of user with id '1' is set to 1:

```
self.get('store').find('user', '1').then(function(user){
     user.get('serviceinfo').then(function(serviceinfo){
          serviceinfo.set('online', 1);
    });
});
```

and after a while, pushPayload is called when a message with userService data(id is '1', online is 2 ) is received:

```
self.get('store').pushPayload('userService', {userService: msg});
```

but the state gotten after that by:

```
self.get('store').getById('user', '1').get('serviceinfo.online');
```

is still '1', that is to say, pushPayload can not change online property in userService model if 'set' is called firstly.

What is the problem?

Comment: Ran into this issue too. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

So `pushPayload` will not overwrite dirty attributes.

To work around this, to `rollbackAttributes` on the record.

PS Thanks to @bmac.